# Trying to get status of a long-running GCP cloud-function process

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am backing up a GCP Firestore database to GCP Cloud Storage using a cloud function that runs nightly. This backup can take several minutes to complete and once it does I want to start another process. To do this I was trying to use the googleapiclient discovery library to periodically check the backup-job's status, and using the example shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/operations/get).

However I am getting an error when I make the call:

```html
 <HttpError 400 when requesting https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/operations/ASAyMjE0ODY2MjUyChp0bHVhZmVkBxJsYXJ0bmVjc3Utc2Jvai1uaW1kYRQKLRI?alt=json returned "field [name] has issue [invalid operation name]". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'name', 'description': 'invalid operation name'}]}]">
```

This seems to suggest that my op_id argument below is incorrectly formatted. Although in what way is unclear to me.

My code looks like this:

```py
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests
from googleapiclient import discovery

...snipping my backup call logic ...

# get the job-id from from the backup call's response. Format of content.name is:
# projects/my-project-name/databases/*/operations/ASAyMjE0ODY2MjUyChp0bHVhZmVkBxJsYXJ0bmVjc3Utc2Jvai1uaW1kYRQKLRI
op_id = content['name'].split('/')[-1] # should be 'operations/[job-id]'

still_running = True

# check status every 10s
while still_running:
    # get status of the backup job
    service = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', cache_discovery=False, credentials=creds)
    service_name = 'operations/{}'.format(op_id)
    service_request = service.operations().get(name=service_name)
    service_response = service_request.execute() #error when called 
    
    if service_response.contains('completed'):
        still_running = False
    else:
        sleep(10)
    ...
```

Any suggestions or insights are appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting the operation name?

Comment: Turns out I hadn't done my research. Its a Firestore type build (not cloud resource manager). Answering below

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I should have read documentation a bit more closely. The HTTP GET call to get the Firestore job status looks like this:

```html
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project-name/databases/*/operations/ASAwNjM2MjQ5MzUyChp0bHVhZmVkBxJsYXJ0bmVjc3Utc2Jvai1uaW1kYRQKLRI"
```

I tried using the googleapiclient discovery pattern from my question but that was unsuccessful. In the end I used a simple Python requests GET call. Problem solved.